# GPU nvidia is not available

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

I am using ubuntu 18.0.4 on a laptop with gpu gtx 1080. Last time, I tested it and It wroks correctly with tensor flow by running this code [test gpu](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu)
Today I discover that the GPU is not recognized by `tensorflow` and when I enter `nvidia-smi` the indicate that the GPU is `off`. What is the problem and how to correct it. I try to set it explicity by running this code, but the mapping does not work:

```
    with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
      a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
      b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
c = tf.matmul(a, b)
# Creates a session with log_device_placement set to True.
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
# Runs the op.
print(sess.run(c))
```

Comment: Why are you using the "with tf.device" to bound it to a cpu?

Comment: @WilliamD.Irons, sorry it was a typo. I mean  `with tf.device('/gpu:0'):`

Comment: How did you install tensorflow? Using pip? Did you install the tensorflow package or tensorflow-gpu package? (I think pip list will show which package is installed?)

Comment: @WilliamD.Irons, I think the problem is coming from python3. When I run the script with just `python (python --version =python 2.7)` the script is running well! How can I change to work with python3.6

Comment: Each python version has it own set of packages, you must have tensorflow-gpu installed with pip and tensorflow installed with pip3? Try pip3 uninstall tensorflow, pip3 install tensorflow-gpu.

Comment: @WilliamD.Irons could we configure to use python3 and python2 with `jupyter notebook` without using anaconda?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know about jupyter notebook environments.

Comment: @WilliamD.Irons Thanks I get it

Comment: Ubuntu18.04 with nvidia MX150 user here. Given that `nvdia-smi` doesn't work I don't think it's the issue with tensorflow or python versioning. Was your `nvidia-smi` command working before you installed tensorflow? If no it means that you need to solve the driver + cuda + cudnn issue first. I personally followed [this guide](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-nvidia-driver-ubuntu-18-04) from a fresh installation and it worked. Maybe you can check if you missed out any steps from that guide?

Answer (score 0):

Run the folowing code to see if your gpu is visible or not

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

if you are only seeing CPU and not GPU then update your cuda and cudnn versions to match with your tensorflow version.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Did you suspend your notebook? Try a full reboot as suspending can make the GPU unavailable after waking up again.